# Recursive function is not returning expected value in PHP

Tags: php, function, recursion, null, return

I'm having trouble with the recursive function I'm trying to write. Here you can see my code:

```
function getParents($individualInfo) {

        $individualid = '';

        if(is_array($individualInfo)) {
            foreach($individualInfo as $key => $value) {
                if(is_array($individualInfo[$key])) {
                    return $this->getParents($individualInfo[$key]);
                }
                else {
                    if ($key == 'individual_id') {
                        $individualid = $individualInfo[$key];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            $individualid = $individualInfo; 
        }
        $q = "SELECT i.individual_id, i.fname, i.lname, i.birth_date, i.death_date, i.gender, 
                i.biography, i.avatar, i.individual_username, r.relationship_individual 
                FROM ".TBL_RELATIONSHIPS." AS r, ".TBL_INDIVIDUALS." AS i
                WHERE r.relationship_individual = '$individualid' 
                AND r.individual = i.individual_id
                AND (r.role = '2')
                LIMIT 2";

        $result = $this->database->query($q);

        if ($result === false) {
            $result .= die(mysql_error());
            return;
        }

        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        $tmp_array = array();


        if ($num_rows > 0) {
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $tmp_array[] = $row;
            }
            foreach ($tmp_array as $tmp_parents) {
                $tmp_parents['individual_id'] = $this->database->cleanOutput($tmp_parents['individual_id']);
                $tmp_parents['fname'] = $this->database->cleanOutput($tmp_parents['fname']);
                $tmp_parents['lname'] = $this->database->cleanOutput($tmp_parents['lname']);
                $tmp_parents['birth_date'] = $this->database->cleanOutput($tmp_parents['birth_date']);
                $tmp_parents['death_date'] = $this->database->cleanOutput($tmp_parents['death_date']);
                $tmp_parents['gender'] = $this->database->cleanOutput($tmp_parents['gender']);
                $tmp_parents['biography'] = $this->database->cleanOutput($tmp_parents['biography']);
                $tmp_parents['avatar'] = $this->database->cleanOutput($tmp_parents['avatar']);
                $tmp_parents['individual_username'] = $this->database->cleanOutput($tmp_parents['individual_username']);
                $tmp_parents['relationship_individual'] = $this->database->cleanOutput($tmp_parents['relationship_individual']);
                // father
                if (!isset($parents[0]) && $tmp_parents['gender'] == 'Male') {
                    $parents[0] = $tmp_parents;
                }
                // mother
                else {
                    $parents[1] = $tmp_parents;
                }
            }
            return $parents;
        }

    }
```

`$this->getParents($this->getParents($individualid));`

Output looks like this if only id is passed, for example 160:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [individual_id] => 161 [fname] => John [lname] => Doe [birth_date] => [death_date] => [gender] => Male [biography] => [avatar] => [individual_username] => [relationship_individual] => 160 ) [1] => Array ( [individual_id] => 162 [fname] => Jane [lname] => Doe [birth_date] => [death_date] => [gender] => Female [biography] => [avatar] => [individual_username] => [relationship_individual] => 160 ) )
```

I want to get these results if I pass the array I posted above to function:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [individual_id] => 163 [fname] => Sr. John [lname] => Doe [birth_date] => [death_date] => [gender] => Male [biography] => [avatar] => [individual_username] => [relationship_individual] => 161 ) [1] => Array ( [individual_id] => 164 [fname] => Sr. Jane [lname] => Doe [birth_date] => [death_date] => [gender] => Female [biography] => [avatar] => [individual_username] => [relationship_individual] => 161 ) )
Array ( [0] => Array ( [individual_id] => 165 [fname] => Sr. John [lname] => Roe [birth_date] => [death_date] => [gender] => Male [biography] => [avatar] => [individual_username] => [relationship_individual] => 162 ) [1] => Array ( [individual_id] => 166 [fname] => Sr. Jane [lname] => Roe [birth_date] => [death_date] => [gender] => Female [biography] => [avatar] => [individual_username] => [relationship_individual] => 162 ) )
```

The function above should help me to find the parents of any given individual or array of individuals. For example, if an array with both parents is passed, then all the data of grandparents is returned. Now, the function doesn't return all the results because I used return statement in the first foreach loop and a function can return only once. However, if I don't use return, null is returned because the $individualid is an empty string at that moment. The function that displays the info look like this:

```
function displayParents($parentsInfo)   {

        foreach ($parentsInfo as $parents) {
            // father
            if (isset($parents[0])) {
                $type = 'father'; 
                $individualid = $parents[0]['individual_id'];
                $name = $parents[0]['fname'].' '.$parents[0]['lname'];
                $bdate = $parents[0]['birth_date'];
                $ddate = $parents[0]['death_date'];
                $gender = $parents[0]['gender'];
                $bio = $parents[0]['biography'];
                $avatar = $parents[0]['avatar'];
                $username = $parents[0]['individual_username'];
                $relationshipid = $parents[0]['relationship_individual'];
                $this->displayLeaf($type, $individualid, $name, $gender, $bdate, $ddate, $bio, $avatar, $username, $relationshipid);
            }
            else {
                $type = 'emptyFather';
                $this->displayLeaf($type, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
            }
            // mother
            if (isset($parents[1])) {
                $type = 'mother'; 
                $individualid = $parents[1]['individual_id'];
                $name = $parents[1]['fname'].' '.$parents[1]['lname'];
                $bdate = $parents[1]['birth_date'];
                $ddate = $parents[1]['death_date'];
                $gender = $parents[1]['gender'];
                $bio = $parents[1]['biography'];
                $avatar = $parents[1]['avatar'];
                $username = $parents[1]['individual_username'];
                $relationshipid = (isset($parents[0]) ? $parents[0]['individual_id'] : $parents[1]['relationship_individual']);
                $this->displayLeaf($type, $individualid, $name, $gender, $bdate, $ddate, $bio, $avatar, $username, $relationshipid);
            }
            else {
                $type = 'emptyMother';
                $this->displayLeaf($type, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
            }
        }
    }
```

I've tried to search for answers to my question but I can't find any solution because I'm really new to it. Any advice on how to change the function to make it do exactly what I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need recursion?

I'm not really 100% clear on what kind of output you expect, if it's just a flat array of all parents of the individuals in the input, then you can easily do without.

```
function getParents($individualInfo) {
    if ( is_integer($individualInfo)) { $individualInfo = array('individual_id' => $individualInfo); }
    if ( isset($individualInfo['individual_id'])) { $individualInfo = array($individualInfo); }
    /* input is now consistently an array of associative arrays that should have a key 'individual_id' */

    $ids = array();
    foreach ($individualInfo as $individual)
    {
        if (!empty($individual['individual_id']) && is_integer($individual['individual_id']) )
        {
            $ids[$individual['individual_id']] = true; 
            /* I'm doing this instead of simply adding the id to the array
               so I can get just the unique ids from the array_keys later*/
        }
    }

    $idsstring = implode(',', array_keys($ids));
    $maxparents = 2*count($ids); /* Well, assuming nuclear families */

    /* there might not be any ids for some reason (like bad input) */
    if (empty($idsstring))
    {
        return array();
    }

    /* we've checked that all ids are integers, so there is little risk of SQL-injection 
    *  With `r.relationship_individual IN ($idsstring)` we can search for all parents of 
    *  all individuals at once.
    */
    $q = "SELECT i.individual_id, i.fname, i.lname, i.birth_date, i.death_date, i.gender, 
            i.biography, i.avatar, i.individual_username, r.relationship_individual 
            FROM ".TBL_RELATIONSHIPS." AS r, ".TBL_INDIVIDUALS." AS i
            WHERE r.relationship_individual IN ($idsstring)
            AND r.individual = i.individual_id
            AND (r.role = '2')
            LIMIT $maxparents";

    $result = $this->database->query($q);

    if ($result === false) {
        $result .= die(mysql_error());
        return;
    }

    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    $tmp_array = array();
    $parents = array();
    if ($num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $tmp_array[] = $row;
        }
        foreach ($tmp_array as $tmp_parents) {
            foreach($tmp_parents as $key => $value){
                $tmp_parents[$key] = $this->database->cleanOutput($value);
            }
            $parents[] = $tmp_parents;
        }
    }
    return $parents;
}
```

If on the other hand you want to build a tree of parents of parents of parents, then recursion might be in order. (Although it's still best avoided for getting the information on the parents from the database. It's more efficient to query the database once.) Let me now if that's the case.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried to use your function and it returned the info of father's father and mother's mother instead of all four grandparents. I'm not sure why it happened but I'll edit my question and explain better what results I would like to get.

Comment: Hmm, well, it's a bit hard to debug without a database (I don't suppose you set the limit to 2?). Maybe you'd be better helped if I suggest a few small fixes to how your original code works now: change `return $this->getParents($individualInfo[$key]);` to `$returned[] = $this->getParents($individualInfo[$key]);` (to collect all returned values from recursion in an array) and before the query, `if($returned) { return $returned; }` (to return the values from the recursion if there were any after we've collected them all)

Comment: Both functions work fine. I figured out that the first one didn't work correctly because the ids weren't unique, so it returned only two grandparents. My original code with the fixes works just fine as well. But I decided not to use recursion after all and query my db only once. I had to make a few changes to the displayParents function and the db but I'm completely happy with the results now. Thank you for your help.